# Module 'Name' is imported from Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-sdk, gradle

Хочу импортировать библиотеку jsoup, но при импорте пишет:

`Module 'MyApp' is imported from Gradle. Any changes made in its configuration may be lost after reimporting.`

Как быть в таком случае? Просто когда писал на Java, проблем с импортом не было, а сейчас под андроид, вот такая ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть в том, что вы (скорее всего) пытаетесь управлять структурой проекта не из `gradle` файла, а напрямую из настроек проекта.

Для того, чтобы вам добавить `jsoup` библиотеку в проект, необходимо добавить `dependency` в ваш `gradle` файл:

```
dependecies{
    //other dependecies

    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.8.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В настройках Idea (в моем случае) в поиске введите 'gradle' и выберите нужную версию[image: Настройки idea/gradle]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]